# LVM и SSD скорость работы

Tags: ssd, lvm

У меня 2 диска в программном RAID1. Попробовал добавить SSD чтобы ускорить работу сайта на битриксе. Сразу подумал, что нужно использовать LVM, чтобы если что без лишних проблем изменять размер томов. Сделал 2 тома, 1 отдал SQL 2 отдал под файлы сайта.

Тестирую инструментами битрикса производительность - скорость записи в БД увеличилось - все ок. А вот файловые операции упали. Вместо 12 000 операций в секунду на программном raid1, показывает 8 800 на ssd.

Я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это достаточно давний вопрос, и его можно заменить на такой:

> Я купил хостинг с SSD диском (дисками), но это не увеличило
>   производительность моего сайта. Почему?

Во-первых, забудьте про битриксовый калькулятор производительности. У меня с ним давние "отношения", и вопросов у меня к нему много. До сих пор я его рассматриваю как инструмент для "обоснования" закупки дополнительного оборудования для хостингового сервера. На его показания любят ссылаться веб-студии, которые поддерживают чей-либо сайт. Основным аргументом в ответе на вопрос заказчика "Почему тормозит мой сайт?" веб-студия отвечает: "А вы купите SSD диск, потому что ваш сервер работает на ржавых дисках".

Так же в ответах может присутствовать еще такой аргумент: "А вот у нас на нашем сервере разработки параметры производительности выше чем эталонные! И у нас все летает!".

В таких случаях я всегда радуюсь за сервер разработки подрядчика.

Второе. Я не отговариваю вас от использования этого калькулятора. Он все же дает некую среднюю температуру по больнице вашего оборудования, измеренную в неких своих "попугаях", но эта информация, с моей точки зрения, должна использоваться для общего понимания о состоянии сервера, чем неким железобетонным аргументом для покупки SSD диска.

Например, один из моих любимых показателей этого калькулятора - количество отправленных писем в единицу времени. Честно скажу, я не изучал код, который это измеряет, но мне всегда было весело, когда при предварительно и намеренно выключенном почтовом сервере, я получал какие-то рандомные значения этого показателя.

Тут замечу, что последний раз я имел дело с битриксовым калькулятором производительности года два (может больше) назад, и за это время возможно он поменялся в каких-то своих частях.

Мое личное мнение - смотреть на его показатели, точнее, относиться к ним "серьезно", надо тогда, когда необходимо выбить из начальства покупку доп.оборудования для сервера, либо, если вы работник веб-студии, то "аргументированно" ответить заказчику, что его сайт тормозит из-за плохих показателей калькулятора.

Но тут как повезет. Если покупка доп.оборудования не решила проблем с общей производительностью, то вы опять в начале пути. И вы в глазах начальства (которому показывали цифры калькулятора), или в глазах заказчика (если вы поддерживаете чей-то сайт) превращаетесь в некомпетентного товарища, который методом тыка и за чужие деньги решает проблему.

Про битрикс-калькулятор всё.

### Теперь немного про общую ситуацию

Ответьте на вопрос (риторический): вы мониторили сервер перед тем как купить диск?

В этом конкретном случае я хочу увидеть статистику (графики) ввода-вывода вашей дисковой подсистемы.

Если у вас этого нет - вы скорее всего просто потратили деньги.

И возвращаясь к нашему основному вопросу "почему SSD не увеличило производительность", коротенько отвечу.

Первое. Операционная система сама неплохо занимается кэшированием операций с диском. В данном случае операции чтения файлов с диска будут в пике в момент рестарта веб-сервера. Затем подавляющее количество этих операций будет происходить из оперативной памяти, что в свою очередь никак не нагружает ввод-вывод диска.

Второе. Операции записи на диск. Это важный момент, но не для движка сайта. Я не веб-девелопер и могу ошибаться, но я не знаю CMS-ок, которые бы нещадно эксплуатировали диск на предмет создания/записи/дозаписи файлов на диске. Равно как и непонятное ("огромное") количество "инсертов" в БД. Все это не про "стандартные" сайты.

Мы сейчас не говорим про системы типа "складывания миллионов/в_минуту CDR (Call Detail Record) в hadoop". Речь исключительно про "сайтики".

### В заключение

У меня в поле зрения есть пару сайтов на битриксе. По роду занятий присматриваю за их "железной" составляющей. Так вот, на дисковом разделе, где лежит весь контент сайта (движок + вся медиа) операций чтения 0.01 в секунду, операций записи около 3,4 в секунду (это видимо кэши битрикса). Поэтому, выдаст мне калькулятор битрикса 10тыщ или 30тыщ операций в секунду с диском, мне от этого будет ни холодно ни жарко.

PS И все таки нам с коллегами было интересно найти узкое место самого битрикса. Прикрутили некий профайлер (от ребят из фэйсбука, если не ошибаюсь). Результаты были интересные. Самая боль у движка была в работе с MySql - большие, неоптимизированные, тяжелые запросы (SELECT-ы), занимающие 60%+ времени генерации страницы. А дисковый ввод-вывод вообще рядом не стоял.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Ставить SSD было просто необходимо, IOwait доходил до 16% при пиковой нагрузке, среднее за сутки 1.5% (сейчас среднее iowait 0.15%). Действительно, битрикс считает все попугаями. Проверил на виртуалке с шустрой схд, цифры скачут, то выше то ниже, и это без нагрузки пользователей.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev совершенно верно! Мы в свое время "выцепили" кусок кода из этого калькулятора, который измеряет дисковые операции и погоняли его на разных устройствах. С большим отрывом выйграл макбук с ssd диском. И почему люди не ставят макбуки в продакшн вместо дорогих и жырных серверов? [сарказм]

Comment: Я профилировал также через XHprof. Почти всегда тормозит БД. Оптимизировать некоторые запросы практически невозможно, конструкция `OR ...` не дает. Не реклама: вот результаты на моем сайте [Профилирование корзины](http://pushorigin.ru/speedup/xhprof-bitix-market) и [Оформление заказа](http://pushorigin.ru/speedup/xhprof-bitix-order)